# Using a Webpage to Control Robot Arm Written in Linux

Tags: html, linux

Firstly I am no longer a student and currently working on a favour for a friend. I am making a website which has a live video feed of a robotic arm and a set off buttons that will allow users with the basic interaction of the robotic arm.

I have setup the website and live video feed. I do have a 4 second delay using flash media encoder and flash server 4.5. Have any suggestions in reducing the delay time?

I have done the python code required for the maplin robotic arm and now I am stuck and not sure how to link my python code with a webpage interface? Can anyone that has done this before provide with code that I could edit and learn from..

Python Code

```
import usb.core
import usb.util
import sys
import time

# This program is intended to control a robotic arm via USB from Linux
# The code is written in Python by Neil Polwart (c) 2011
# It is a work in progress and will improved!

# locate the device device

dev = usb.core.find(idVendor=0x1267, idProduct=0x0000)

# assigns the device to the handle "dev"
# can check the device is visible to Linux with command line command lsusb
# which should report a device with the above vendor and id codes.

# was it found?

if dev is None:
raise ValueError('Device not found')           # if device not found report an       error


# set the active configuration

dev.set_configuration()

# as no arguments, the first configuration will be the active one
# note as commands are sent to device as commands not data streams 
# no need to define the endpoint

# defines the command packet to send

datapack=0x80,0,0

# change this packet to make different moves.  
# first byte defines most of the movements, second byte shoulder rotation, third           byte light
# command structure in more detail:
# http://notbrainsurgery.livejournal.com/38622.html?view=93150#t93150

print "requested move",datapack    # reports the requested movement to the user

# send the command

bytesout=dev.ctrl_transfer(0x40, 6, 0x100, 0, datapack, 1000)

# outputs the command to the USB device, using the ctrl_transfer method
# 0x40, 6, 0x100, 0 defines the details of the write - bRequestType, bRequest,    wValue, wIndex
# datapack is our command (3 bytes)
# the final value is a timeout (in ms) which is optional
# bytesout = the number of bytes written (i.e. 3 if successful)

print "Written :",bytesout,"bytes"  # confirm to user that data was sent OK

# wait for a defined period

time.sleep(1)    # waits for 1 second whilst motors move.

# now STOP the motors

datapack=0,0,0

bytesout=dev.ctrl_transfer(0x40, 6, 0x100, 0, datapack, 1000)

if bytesout == 3: print "Motors stopped"
```

So I need to find a way to edit the datapack line via a website interface. Any help is appreciated! I am using a Windows 7 setup but do have access to vmware

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd set up an Apache server with [`mod_python`](http://modpython.org/) and create a handler that imports your script and runs the necessary code.  You can set up an AJAX script in JavaScript (with or without [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)).  Every time you want to run the Python script, a request needs to be made to the server.  You can pass any information back and forth as needed via the HTTP.

---

Here's a [good tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_cgi_programming.htm) for Python and the CGI Module.

Comment: Anyway you could give me a more detailed guide or examples of how I would create the handler? Ive already CDN linked to jQuery, is it easier with jQuery?

Comment: jQuery makes it quite a bit easier.  If you already have it on the page, there's no reason not to use it.  I'll see what I can do with instructions.

Comment: Very much appreciated, I need to finish this off my tomorrow afternoon. Think I am going to stay up tonight :|